# React js google maps update marker only if position changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I have a component that shows a google map with two markers. two different forms that update the same state. I have 4 fields that allow the user to edit the lat and long for the two makers. But now the map re-redners every time a field value is changed making the application very slow when editing

```
<FormGroup>
                        <FormControl
                            type="decimal"
                            required
                            label="Latitude"
                            placeholder="Latitude"
                            value={latitude}
                            onChange={e => this.onFormChange('latitude', e)}
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <FormControl
                            type="decimal"
                            required
                            label="Longitude"
                            placeholder="Longitude"
                            value={longitude}
                            onChange={e => this.onFormChange('longitude', e)}
                        />
</FormGroup>
```

I only want to re-render coordinates these values are changed and if new props values are different then before. Is there a lifecycle function where I check that?

Comment: With component re-render `componentwillreceiveprops` will called,you use it.If you using v<16.3

Comment: I do that but the next props are always equal to the current props

Comment: Could u please add marker related stuff